# Embed Excel Sheet into Asp.Net Web Page

Tags: embed

I need to know that is there any way through which i can embed Excel sheet into ASP.Net Web page,format can be .xls or .xlsx.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

For my needs i use the  [Google docs viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer)

You can point it to your url and specify the embed option using an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=YOUR_URL_TO_YOUR_XLS&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks,but can you please tell how to give the URL if my Excel file in D drive,like D:\\Book1.xlsx

Comment: @Ankit your excel file has to be uploaded to an online destination first. maybe your website. you'll then pass the url to the viewer.

Comment: @Ankit yes you can but the file cannot be in a local destination. you have to upload it to an online destination.

Comment: for this sake i am adding my file into one of my Application folder,but from there also it is not working.I have configured my application in local IIS, so from there also it has to behave the same.

Comment: @Ankit Can i access your excel file if you give me the url u are using? if i can then google viewer can't. The url has to be publicly available.